how to prove the inequalities in a SFWG article?
In professor Ye and Zhang's article, Four‑Order Superconvergent Weak Galerkin Methods
for the Biharmonic Equation on Triangular Meshes, https://doi.org/10.1007/s42967-022-00201-5, they proved a norm-inequality
$C_1 \|v\|_{2,h}\leq|||v|||\leq C_2 \|v\|_{2,h}$. And in the proof, they proved that there is a unique $\tau$ which satisfies the inequality $\|\tau\|_0 \leq C\|v\|_{2,h}$.
I just can prove $\|\text{divdiv}\tau\|_0\leq C\|v\|_{2,h}$, but cannot prove $\|\text{divdiv}\tau\|_0$ is a norm.
The question is how to prove $\|\text{divdiv}\tau\|_0$ is a norm so that I can use finite dimensional norm equivalence to achieve $\|\tau\|_0 \leq C\|v\|_{2,h}$.
Thank u!!!

$|div div(\cdot)|_0$ is not a norm on general finite element spaces, as there are many non zero functions that have a norm of zero under that operation (looks more like a semi norm). To make it a norm you need to consider a subspace that has e.g. zero boundary condition for the functions and their gradients. You can then apply a discrete point are Friedrichs inequality to get the rest you are after.
